# Join query in SQLite iPhone

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have two tables `Visits` and `Labs`
Visit has these fields: `id`,`patientID`
Labs has these fields: `id`, `VisitID`
`And Visit.id = Labs.VisitID`

I want to get all old lab reports of a patient. But in lab table I don't have `patientID` field,
so for that I need to make use of `visitID` field, using which I can connect to Visit table and there I have `patientID`

So now using `visitID`(a common field) I want to find out all old lab reports of a patient

Now I want to get all labs of a patient (I know `patientID`)

Can anyone suggest me join query for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple `INNER JOIN`, right?

```
SELECT labs.* FROM labs INNER JOIN visit ON visit.id = labs.visitID AND patientID = ?
```

Or you can do a subselect:

```
SELECT labs.* FROM labs WHERE visitID IN (SELECT visit.id FROM visit WHERE patientID = ?)
```

Comment: By the way, I assume that the table name is "visit" and not "visits". You refer to it both ways in your original question.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked like a charm

I am weak at Joins so i had to ask this

Looking at your query, i can understand what its going to do but i can't write query on my Own,

Once again Thank you