# How to get the join data from sqlite table in iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite, join

I am using join to get the the data from sqlite table here is the my query

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID  LEFT JOIN Topic ON ContentMaster.TopicID=Topic.TopicID where ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@' OR Category.CategoryName='%@' AND Topic.TopicName='%@'",appDelegate.tagInput,appDelegate.categoryName,appDelegate.topicName];
```

it works fine but I want to also get `Category.CategoryName` and `Topic.TopicName` using this query so how to get and when I get that row like following how to give number

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            Content *coffeeObj = [[Content alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            coffeeObj.categoryID  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,1)];
            coffeeObj.topicID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,2)];
            coffeeObj.contentType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,3)];
            coffeeObj.contentTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,4)];
            coffeeObj.contentAddedByUserID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,5)];
            coffeeObj.contentDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,6)];
            coffeeObj.contentFileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,7)];
            coffeeObj.contentSavedFileLocation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,8)];
            coffeeObj.contentSize = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,9)];
            coffeeObj.contentAddedDateTime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,10)];
            coffeeObj.hiveletCode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,11)];
            coffeeObj.contentTagText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,12)];
            coffeeObj.views = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,13)];

            coffeeObj.userName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,14)];
            }}
```

if I will get `CategoryName` I have to write 15 or anything else and how to get in query also.

Comment: Don't use `select *`, use `select` with an explicit column name list.

Comment: @maddy Category Name is in Category table and TopicName is in Topic table how to get both and give them below row number

Comment: As I said, explicitly list them in the `select` clause.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738125/join-query-in-sqlite-iphone check it helpful for you